# ModuleNotFoundError：No module named 'homeapp'

Tags: python-3.x, django-views

The structure of my project is the next：

MyProject

apps

homeapp

admin.py

apps.py

migrations

init__.py

models.py

tests.py

views.py

**init**.py

urls.py

homeapp-views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
def home(request):
return render(request, 'home.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from homeapp.views import home
```

python3.7+django2.2

I don't know how to describe my question when I was searching.Is it "How to import a module from a different folder in Python?"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please try to not post images of code / errors so it can be easier for us to help you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: What you are looking for are [relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) in python.